# How to check whether item is being added or updated in PreSaveAction

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, client-object-model, client-side-rendering

I am using the PreSaveAction JavaScript function to handle list item add and edit operations. But depending upon whether the item is being added ( newform.aspx ) or being updated ( editform.aspx ) I need to implement separate functionality.

How can I check this in PreSaveAction?

or is there any other function to override?

Comment: How are you overriding PreSaveAction? As you noted, there are two different pages for the New and Edit forms, so if you're adding the PreSaveAction override method directly to the forms (such as via a content editor web part with a content link property to an html file), there should be no need to differentiate-- you'd just have different code on each form.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a proper way to do this, but until then I'll just leave this ugliness for now:

```
var isEditForm = !!window.location.href.match(/editform\.aspx/i);
```

(Note custom forms will have a different url, so this is not a very good solution).

**Update 1:**
As commented by @PirateEric looking for ID querystring parameter is another option.
E.g.,

```
var isEditForm = !!window.location.search.match(/id=\d+/i)
```

**Update 2:**
As mentioned in comments `JSRequest.QueryString["ID"]` can be used to get the ID querystring. It must first be initialized with `JSRequest.EnsureSetup();`

Another option is to use `GetUrlKeyValue`. I have tested this on 2010, 2010 custom forms, 2013, 2013 custom forms, O365 and O365 with custom forms and it works in all.
This is the snippet I used:

```
var isEditForm = !!(GetUrlKeyValue('ID') || GetUrlKeyValue('id'));
```

ID is as far as I know always upper case, but it is best to be on the safe side.

Comment: Another alternative would just be looking for the existance of the ID query string param, no ID, newform, ID exists, editform

Comment: @PirateEric Good call! Updated answer. If you have a better match please share (quick fix intead of [larger solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript))

Comment: You can use the built in JSRequest object, it would be something like this: `JSRequest.QueryString["ID"]`, that would check right away for the ID in the query string.

Comment: @MohamedDerhalli `JSRequest.QueryString` doesn't seem to always be populated, actually didn't get populated for me on any of these: 2010 form, 2010 custom form, 2013 form, 365 form or 365 custom form

Comment: How about `GetUrlKeyValue`. I have seen it working in SP 2010, SP 2013 and O365. Note that `ID` is case sensitive

Comment: @eirikb, you need to use: `JSRequest.EnsureSetup();` to make sure that the JSRequest object is ready to use, then you can use the object.

Comment: I kind of like @NadeemYousuf s suggestion, perhaps something like `var isEditForm = !!(GetUrlKeyValue('ID') || GetUrlKeyValue('id'))`?

Comment: @eirikb, by the way did you try `WPQ2FormCtx`? Any reason why this should not be used given that one of the tags by OP is client side rendering which may mean user is on 2013.

Comment: @NadeemYousuf Tested it on O365, and it was not available on O365 custom forms, I suspect the same is true for on-premise.

Comment: @eirikb, I just created a custom new form by copying the original new form and it shows up there.

Comment: @NadeemYousuf I created an edit form by clicking _Forms_ -> _New..._ in SharePoint Designer

Comment: @eirikb, you are right. It doesn't appear there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in SharePoint 2013, you can use OOB object `WPQ2FormCtx`. It has a property named `FormControlMode` which gives the mode of the form. For EditForm the value is 2 and for NewForm the value is 3. So, use `WPQ2FormCtx.FormControlMode`.